# Which Logo communicates more "professionalism and luxury"?

Tags: logo, critique, branding

Edit: New logo after hearing great critics here:

[image]So I created a Logo for a company which they accepted and liked more than the old one. However, they asked me if I believe the new one communicated more luxury, trust and professionalism than the old one.

Does it communicate more professionalism if yes then why?

Both are unfortunately at a lower resolution after uploading.

[image: The Companies Logo]

Comment: Which is their current logo, and which did you create?

Comment: @EddieA. Thanks for asking. The larger top one is the new one created, below the old. Basically the company sells services in the areas of psychology, fortune telling etc

Comment: The top choice is better, but both convey unprofessionalism and being cheap to me. Why is the O raised? What does the line mean? I think the gradient is what makes it look especially cheap-looking to me

Comment: @ZachSaucier Raising the O would give it some extra spice and should represent some sort of all seeing eye since they do fortune telling. The line is an eyebrow. I agree with the gradients and im not happy with the line.

Comment: Hi user3724954, thanks for your question. Critique questions are a bit of a weird fit here, because they don't always match with our intended Q&A format. Please have a peek at [our guidelines for critique questions](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/681/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work) and see whether you can make yours fit those. Thanks!

Comment: Hello Vincent, thank you for the information. I will do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luxury is not something generally connected to trust and professionalism. I'm not convinced the 3 concepts are compatible with each other. Neither do I associate psychology and "fortune telling" with each other.

The gradient in the text is currently out of fashion, so it's not going to engender trust or professionalism, it's going to indicate that they're somewhat behind the times.

Your type choice is nice, it's a clean high-class font. I would think about creating a logo mark (like a golden eye/eyebrow) that sits on top of the wordmark.

Comment: The golden eyebrow is a great idea and I agree with the gradient what you are saying. I created a new logo based on all the critics and placed it in my question. In regards to the gradients, I changed it to a hopefully better gold. I think flat design is really nice but in this case I thought that everybody uses flat now, so if I were to create a subtle gold effect that that would stand out more.

Comment: the new one looks much better. Try it at different sizes - you may need to adjust your fills for when the logo is very small. What will you use for a favicon? The O with the dot?

Comment: Yes, you got it. The O fits nicely I think

Answer (score 2):

What represents luxury and professionalism is subjective. Changing the font to all caps helps slightly and I liked that you reduced the strength of the gradient.

What I don't understand is the dot in the center of the O, why the baseline of the O is raised and what the curved line above the typography is for.

I'm curious, did you do any other iterations of the logo design? In my opinion this version could use more refinements.

Comment: This is the only version. The dot represents an "eye" because the companies see through your mind (analyzing, pschology etc). The curved line represents an eyebrow.